# How to fix var when jsFiddle says var already defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/juggernautsei/w8yn2ehk/
My jquery has gotten very rusty. The system says I have to put the code in here so here is a snippet below.

```
$(function() {

    $("input[name$='notify_type']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        var selected = $("input[type='radio'][id='notify_type3']:checked").val();

        $("div.referral").hide();
        $("#ref" + test).show();

          if(selected == "4") var opts = [
        {name: "Please Select", val:""},
        {name:"WMOX", val:"WMOX"},
        {name:"WVKL", val:"WVKL"},
        {name:"WJDQ", val:"WJDQ"},
        {name:"WOWI", val:"WOWI"},
        {name:"WTOK", val:"WTOK"}
    ];
```

On the left is a list of referral types. I want the block on the left to change depending on the type of referral that is selected. Most of that is accomplished.
What I want to happen is notify_type3 should populate the dropdown list on the right according to the list type selected on the left. The first one works correctly. The rest do not. I think I need an on change but not sure where to place it. Suggestions please

Comment: am not sure what is the "first one" and what is rest? Side note" On your fiddle you have the **same id** `notify_type3` for more than one input.

Comment: I did that because I wanted those to have the same behavior as with the show hide were all the ID's are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few problems. Two main ones:

1) The way you were getting `selected` only worked for the first one. For the others `selected` got the value `undefined`.

2) The way you decided which block on the right were to be shown (`$("#ref" + test).show();`) didn't work since test could have a value between 1 and 10 and you only had ref elements for 1-4.

Here is the changes I made: https://jsfiddle.net/w8yn2ehk/41/

Please note is still doesn't work for 7-10 because I only fixed the ones using the select block (ref3), but with this info it shouldn't be a problem to fix the rest.